# Right + Application.UserName

Tags: vba

I am trying to combine functions RIGHT and Application.UserName.

The user name is Smith, John. I want to have only name - John.
I tried to do it like below, but it doesn't work.

```
Sub test ()
Dim x as string
x = Right(Application.Username, Len(Application.UserName) - Application.UserName.Find(" ",Application.UserName, 1))
End Sub
```

Could you please advise?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Find` method of `Application.UserName`.

Use `Split`:

```
Dim splitName
splitName = Split(Application.UserName)

Debug.Print splitName(Ubound(splitName)) '<~ returns John
```

Comment: Works. Thank you :)